# MySQL won't recognize ALTER on timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp, alter

I have a MySQL oddity I haven't seen before and could use some help.

I have a users table that was created (not by me) with these two fields:

```
`date_entered` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`date_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

These are the only 2 timestamp in the table.

However, that's incorrect so I ran this update statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` 
  CHANGE `date_entered` `date_entered` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  CHANGE `date_modified` `date_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

This works fine on my localhost (Wampserver MySQL 5.6.17) but does not work on my production machine (Windows MySQL 5.6.16) and keeps defaulting back to having the DEFAULT set for both fields.

Is there something I need to configure in MySQL or somewhere else to get rid of these defaults? I'd like to remove both but especially the ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP since it makes the data wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm somewhat curious why you're running mismatched versions between your dev machine and your production machine?  I'm hardly an expert when it comes to MySQL, but generally speaking it's pretty much always a good idea to have your dev software mirror whatever's on your production box...

Comment: I agree, but I don't generally work on this production machine and was hoping not to need to setup a new environment since they are pretty close and it's not doing much beyond basic CRUD operations.

Comment: Update: I can set the timestamps to NULL and it seems ok and at least gets rid of the ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but I would like to know why one MySQL server would allow no default while the other seems to require it.